# Failing to write to iCloud Drive

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, icloud-drive

I'm having an hard time with iCloud Drive in my app. I cannot create my app's folder in iCloud Drive.

Somehow, yesterday, I managed to create the folder and save items there, but today, after I run my code, the folder is gone and I cannot save files anymore.

Here's a sample code that I have managed to run and put to work yesterday:

```
let str = "ivan cantarino"

guard let iCloudPath = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents") else {
    print("Failed to get iCloud path")
    return
}

print("icloud path:", iCloudPath.absoluteString)
// prints: icloud path: file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~com~ivancantarino~Cozynote/Documents

let lastPath = iCloudPath.appendingPathComponent("iCloudDrive.txt")

// writes a file to the directory
do {
    try str.write(to: lastPath, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
    print("success")
} catch {
    print("failed to write with error:", error.localizedDescription)
    // prints: failed to write with error: The file “iCloudDrive.txt” couldn’t be saved in the folder “Documents”.
}
```

Here's my info.plist iCloud info:

```
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
<dict>
    <key>iCloud.com.ivancantarino.Cozynote</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
        <string>Cozynote</string>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
        <string>Any</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Here's a print, showing that I'm using the proper container:

[image]

I have bumped the app's version and build number, reinstalled the app, but somehow I cannot write to the path.
It keeps printing the error.

Can anyone spot anything I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked on an app that depends heavily on iCloud drive , Bottom line it's the worst . hard to debug unpredictable and poorly documented  .

So i can give you a couple of options to try and see if it helps . 
One of the things that could greatly help you is creating `UIDocument` SubClass , these can talk pretty well with iCloud Drive.

```
 class TextDoc:UIDocument{
    var data:String?


    override func contents(forType typeName: String) throws -> Any {
        return data?.data(using: .utf8) ?? Data()
    }

    override func load(fromContents contents: Any, ofType typeName: String?) throws {
        if let userContent = contents as? Data {
            data = String(data: userContent, encoding: .utf8)
        }
    }

}


let folder = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Folder")

try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: folder?.path ?? "", withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

let fileURL = folder?.appendingPathComponent("iCloudDrive.txt")

let uiDoc = TextDoc(fileURL: fileURL!)
uidoc.save(to: url, for: .forOverwriting) { (success) in
    print("save was \(success)")
}
```

If the saving was successful you can open it using `open(completionHandler: <#T##((Bool) -> Void)?##((Bool) -> Void)?##(Bool) -> Void#>)`

Also make sure you've iCloud Set correctly in developer.apple.com 
[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'll test this and will provide feedback ;)

Comment: It saved the file to iCloud Drive, though I cannot find it by searching manually in the Files app, nor it didn't create my App's folder within the iCloud Drive.
Is there a way to visualize the folder?

Comment: yes you can use your mac to do that , open terminal  
cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/iCloud\~com\~ivancantarino\~Cozynote/ 
then explore using cd and ls the directories of your app